# user ubuntu does not have access to /home/ubuntu/.ssh on ubuntu server 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, server

I can cd to .ssh directory. But I do not even have the access to execute ls command.
It says:

```
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

Not even to say writing file in this directory.
What cause this issue and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're entering `/home/ubuntu/.ssh` with `ubuntu` user, the most like reason why you don't have access to that directory is that it has been created with another user (e.g. root, if you did it with sudo).

First, take ownership of the folder with:
`sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/.ssh`

Then, set appropriate permissions with:
`sudo chmod 700 /home/ubuntu/.ssh`.

Your `authorized_keys` file must have a 600 permissions, so fix it later if you're going to use it.

Comment: May I know the difference between first step and second one? After `chown` operation, I can perform command normally. Why it is necessary to set permissions. And why `authorized_keys` must have a 600 permissions?

Comment: The `chown` command sets ownership. Every file or folder has owner - user and group. `chmod` sets the permissions. In linux, the files and folders permissions are visible for the user in binary: 
`rwxrwxrwx`. The first 3 bits are for the user, the second 3 bits are for the group, and the 3rd 3 bits are for Everyone. What does that mean: if a file has `400` permissions (equals 100-000-000 or r-- --- ---) that means that only the owner user can read it, others cannot. If it has r00-r00-000 it means that the owner user and all members of the owner group can read it.

Comment: Setting appropriate permissions improve security and reduce the risk of you or someone else mixing things up.

`authorized_keys` must have `600` permissions, because only the owner must be able to read/write to it.